# AMPscript Error

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Can anybody tell me what the issue about the code below? Just try to debugg since an hour, but can't find anything. The IF Case is working. For the ELSE case the landingpage always through an error.

```
%%[
VAR @campaign
SET @campaign = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Campaign", "Id", "Id", "=", "XXXXXXXXXXXXX")
]%%

%%[IF RowCount(@campaign) == 1 THEN]%% 
Success
%%[ELSE]%%
Error
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: Got it: If you use the RetrieveSalesforceObjects function an use the Salesforce ID as condition in the search, it through an error if the Id is invalid. In my case I created a custom field in Saleforce with a formula to get the 18 digit id and used that field in the condition.

Comment: Good stuff!!! please post it as an answer so everyone can learn from it

Comment: Why are you checking the row count on `@sfcampaign` when the rowset is stored in `@campaign`?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I pass the campaignId from Url Parameter, and I need to verify the CampaignId for existance. RowCount 1 = exists, rowcount 0 = wrong Id. Or what do you mean?

Comment: I think you're using the wrong variable in your rowcount() function.  Seems like it should be `IF RowCount(@campaign) == 1 THEN`

Comment: Gotcha! This was a copy & paste issue. Wanted to make the variable as clean as possible here at stackoverflow. All variables are called sfcampaign in my actual script. Just updated it.

Answer (score 2):

Got it: If you use the RetrieveSalesforceObjects function and use the Salesforce ID as a condition in the search, it throws an error if the Id is invalid. In my case, I created a custom field in Salesforce with a formula to get the 18 digit id and used that field in the condition.

Comment: Good catch... have you tried catching an exception for it? So it's doesn't the errors don't cancel your sends i.e. If a triggered send cancels too many times it would cancel the send

Comment: how can you handle exceptions? And is it actually possible to display exceptions on landingpages?